# Plus construction on presheaf iff isomorphism

Tags: logic, homotopy-theory, sheaf-theory

This is from *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*, III5. Lemma 2, Moerdijk and Mac Lane.

On a site $(\mathcal C, J)$, and given a  prehseaf $P$

> Define the plus construction by$$P^+(U) = \underrightarrow{\mathrm{lim}}_{R \in J(U)} Match(R, P)$$

The claim is

> If $\eta: P \rightarrow P^+$ is an isomoprhism then $P$ is a sheaf.
>
> $\eta$ sends $x \in P(C)$ to the matching fmaily $\{x \cdot f \,
> : \, f \in t_C \}$ where $t_C$ is maximal sieve.

I see how being mono shows $P$ is separated.

**But how does surjectivity imply the existence ?**

Concern: given a matching family for a sieve $S$,
$$\{x_f \, : \, f \in S \} $$
to say that $\eta$ is surjective, implies there exists a *refinement $T \subseteq S$*
$$ \{x_f \,:\, f \in T \} $$
is restriction fo $x \in P(C)$. This is *weaker* than what we need.

Comment: Isn't a refinement a bigger sieve ?

Comment: That's also a confusion I have, but a refinement seems to be smaller in the text.